# Missing Properties from Type that shouldn't have to be passed manually to child component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

In my child component I am defining the Props interface and include it in the React.Component.

These Props are then required to be passed to the child component from the parent component. So far so good, this all makes sense..

However when I extend the Props interface with i.e. RouteComponentProps from react-router Typescript also requires me to pass 'history, location, match', which I don't think I am supposed to pass manually...

I don't think it is related specifically to RouteComponentProps, as in certain cases I run into the same error with MapDispatchToProps and the PropsFromDispatch interface - a more elaborate explanation of this case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53994860/mapdispatchtoprops-causes-typescript-error-in-parent-component-expecting-action)

Here is my code:

/Child.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router';

interface Props extends RouteComponentProps { }

class Child extends React.Component<Props> {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>

            </div>
        )
    }
 }

export default Child;
```

/Parent.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react'
import Child from './Child';

export default class Parent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Child />
             </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Error in /Parent.tsx:

```
<Child/>

Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 
'Readonly<Props>': history, location, match - ts(2739)
```

Typescript and React versions:

> "typescript": "^3.2.1", "react": "^16.6.3", "@types/react": "^16.7.13"

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Try updating your `@types/react` to `16.7.3`

Comment: @HarishSoni just tried it now and didn't help :/

Comment: let me know if my answer works for you?

Answer (score 5):

So the problem is being caused by the `Props` which are marked as required in the `RouteComponentProps` class.

As you workaround you need to export your class `as any`, it will export your class without any type.

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { RouteComponentProps, withRouter } from 'react-router';

interface Props extends RouteComponentProps { }

class ChildImpl extends React.Component<Props> {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>

            </div>
        )
    }
 }
const Child = withRouter(ChildImpl as any);//Note: It is a workaround not an actual solution
export default Child;
```

And then in your parent:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import Child from './Child';
export default class Parent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Child />
             </div>
        )
    }
}
```

No Props will be required to pass.

Comment: hmm ok the error in Parent.tsx disappears, but when I now try to use i.e. this.props.history.push('/') I get TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined.. (I am using BrowserRouter to wrap everything in app.tsx)

Comment: Yeah because you need to use `withRouter` in order to use `history`

Comment: Just Updated my answer for `Child` component see how I am exporting the Child Component and use the same.
Please do a upvote and accept it as answer if it solves your issue thanks

Comment: This is right but if you don't want to pass props to your component just use RouteComponentProps as Props and problem solved.

Also you don't need to export 'as any'.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and the idea from @goediaz works fine to me, the only diference was I'm working with funcional components.

```
const MyFunciont: React.FC<IGlobalState> = (_RouteComponentProps, props) = {
//here your code

return (
    //html code
    )
}
```