# Argument of type '(dispatch: Dispatch<any>, ownProps: OwnProps) => DispatchProps' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DispatchProps'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I'm creating a react app using redux and typescript as language. I was following the advises of this [post](https://medium.com/knerd/typescript-tips-series-proper-typing-of-react-redux-connected-components-eda058b6727d) to create types for `mapStateToProps` and `maptDispatchToProps` function. This is my container:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { AppState } from 'src/store';
import { changeFilter } from 'src/store/tasks/actions';
import { Dispatch } from 'redux';
import {  VisibilityFilter } from 'src/store/tasks/types';
import * as React from 'react';

 interface OwnProps {
    filter: VisibilityFilter;
  }

  interface StateProps {
    active: boolean
  }

  interface DispatchProps {
    onClick: () => void
  }

  type Props = StateProps & DispatchProps & OwnProps

  export const Filter: React.FC<Props> = props => {
    const { active, onClick, children } = props;

    return (
      <button
        onClick={onClick}
        disabled={active}
        style={{
          marginLeft: "4px"
        }}
      >
        {children}
      </button>
    );
  };


const mapStateToProps = (state: AppState, ownProps: OwnProps): StateProps => ({
    active: ownProps.filter === state.tasksState.visibilityFilter
  })

  const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch<any>, ownProps:OwnProps): DispatchProps => ({
    onClick: () => dispatch(changeFilter(ownProps.filter))
  })

  export default connect<StateProps,DispatchProps,OwnProps>(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
  )(Filter)
```

But I'm having the following error in the `connect` function saying this for the `mapDispatchToProps` function:

> Argument of type '(dispatch: Dispatch, ownProps: OwnProps) =>
>   DispatchProps' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DispatchProps'.
>   Property 'onClick' is missing in type '(dispatch: Dispatch,
>   ownProps: OwnProps) => DispatchProps' but required in type
>   'DispatchProps'.ts(2345) Filter.tsx(17, 5): 'onClick' is declared
>   here. Filter.tsx(49, 5): Did you mean to call this expression?

Is there something wrong with my `DispatchProps` type that `connect` function is rejecting it?

In case you need to know these are the libraries I'm using:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-redux": "^7.0.2",
    "react-scripts-ts": "3.1.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.11",
    "@types/node": "^11.13.4",
    "@types/react": "^16.8.13",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.8.4",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.0.6",
    "typescript": "^3.4.3"
  }
```

### Update

If I remove the generic types in the `connect` function then the error disappear here and it infers the types:

[image: connect function]

But now when I use `Filter` container is forcing me to add onclick prop in the definition:

[image: using container]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53994860/mapdispatchtoprops-causes-typescript-error-in-parent-component-expecting-action). There is a type defined for generic `Dispatch` that is called `AnyAction` that is part of redux library, so `mapDispatchToProps` should be:

```
 const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch<AnyAction>, ownProps:OwnProps): DispatchProps => ({
    onClick: () => dispatch(changeFilter(ownProps.filter))
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch<any>, ownProps:OwnProps): DispatchProps => ({
    onClick: () => dispatch(changeFilter(ownProps.filter))
  })
```

do this

```
    //in the import section 
    import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
        const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch<any>, ownProps:OwnProps): DispatchProps => {
            return bindActionCreators ({

            changeFilter         }),
dispatch
 }
```

the `mapDispatchToProps` in your case returning an object that contains an onClick function, which is not the expected behaviour of it

Comment: I tried removing the parenthesis but that didn't fix it. According with the `DispatchProps` type I should return an object with an `onClick` function.